# Is there any way to tell a View it's being recycled by a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to free some objects when a `View` is recycled by a `RecyclerView`. After this cleanup is done, the View must be re-bound via `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder()` before it can be used again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the place to do this is `RecyclerView.Adapter.onViewRecycled()`